# Titanium IOS minimum version xml tag not working

Tags: javascript, ios, xml, titanium-alloy

Ive gotten an error that a lot of people have gotten on here when i try to compile my tianium project on ios (im using an old iPhone 3s running iOS 6.1.6)

```
`[ERROR] :  This app does not support the device "Ianturner1989’s iPhone"
The device is running iOS 6.1.6, however the app's the minimum iOS version is set to 7.0
In order to install this app on this device, lower the <min-ios-ver> to 6.1 in the tiapp.xml:
<ti:app xmlns:ti="http://ti.appcelerator.org">
    <ios>
        <min-ios-ver>6.1</min-ios-ver>
    </ios>
</ti:app>`
```

but when i enter this in tiapp.xml nothing changes, the exact same error occurs. HAs anyone else encountered this?

Comment: what version of titanium sdk are you using?